# How does Python store data returned from a function when used in another function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, debugging

I have been trying to do an animation using data stored in a file. With FuncAnimation I managed to create a function that made the animation, so I could call that function in some other module. Unfortunately, even though it works fine if I just call the function, it won't work if I call it inside some other function.

This is the function I created:

```
def animate_solar_system(datafile, colors=None):
    def readdatafile(datafile):
        data = pd.read_csv(datafile)  # Read the CSV file
        planet_columns = [col for col in data.columns if 'Position' in col]  # Select position columns
        planet_names = [col.split('_')[2] for col in planet_columns if 'x' in col]
        orbit_data = []
        for j, planet in enumerate(planet_names):
            orbit_data.append([[data[planet_columns[3*j]][k], data[planet_columns[3*j+1]][k]] for k in range(len(data[planet_columns[0]]))])
        orbit_coor = np.array(orbit_data)
        return planet_names, orbit_coor

    [names, orbit_coor] = readdatafile(datafile)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-2e11, 2e11), ylim=(-2e11, 2e11))  # Will have to change it for the maximum radius
    points = [ax.plot([], [], 'o', color=colors[i], label=name)[0] for i, name in enumerate(names)]  # Changed here to plot points instead of lines
    texts = [ax.text(0, 0, name, ha='right') for name in names]  # Initialize text positions

    def init():
        for point, text in zip(points, texts):
            point.set_data([], [])
            text.set_position((0, 0))  # Initialize text positions
        return points + texts

    def animate(i):
        for j, point in enumerate(points):
            point.set_data(orbit_coor[j][i, 0], orbit_coor[j][i, 1])  # Changed here to plot a single point at each step
            texts[j].set_position((orbit_coor[j][i, 0], orbit_coor[j][i, 1]))  # Update text positions
        return points + texts

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=len(orbit_coor[0]),
                                  interval=100, blit=True)

    return ani
```

it reads the csv file with the positions of every astro using readdatafile() and then makes the animation with the rest of the code. if I call the function with

```
datafile = 'positions.dat'
colors = ['y', 'b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'k']
animation = AniFunction.animate_solar_system2(datafile, colors)
```

it works from any module. This is how it should look like:

[image: This is how it should look like]

However, if I try to call the same function from my main() function, which computes all the positions that are used later, the axes and the figure will appear, but not the points, as if the datafile was empty. This is what it shows:

[image: This is what it shows]

Trying to spot where the bug is I tried printing something but I mistakenly typed `print(a)` instead of `print('a')`, and an error popped up, since `a` is a variable I didn't define before. Surprisingly, terminating the code with the error made the animation appear, while the animation was empty if there was no error. This made me think Python stores data in some kind of way I can't really understand and is messing with my code. Can someone share any insight of why this happens and how to avoid it?

Comment: The `FuncAnimation` object has to continue to exist in memory for the animation it represents to continue playing.  Store it in a variable, append it to a list, assign it as an attribute of some object that will continue to exist - anything that keeps the object alive.

Comment: I am already assigning it to the variable `animation` so it should still be stored.

Comment: The function uses a global variable `animation`. Where does that come from? Your top-level code assigns that variable when the function returns, how is it assigned before the call?

Comment: If you move the calling code into a function, `animation` will become a local variable, not a global variable.

Comment: But if `animation` is local to the module that defines the function, this shouldn't be an issue, the two variables are unrelated. Can you add the definition of the `main()` function that has the problem?

Comment: That was it, declaring the variable as a global variable makes it work. Since the `main()` wasn't returning anything the animation data must have been deleted. Thanks.